# Problems with adding +1 (period) and -1 day with dateutil's relativedelta

Tags: python, date, relativedelta

I'm getting a class typeerror using dateutil's relative delta. My code is here:

```
#import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Series

#timing
pers = 12
monthpp = 1
month_per = int(pers/monthpp)

sdate = dt.date(2016,1,1)
ops = dt.date(2016,3,15)

bop1 = sdate
eop1 = bop1 + relativedelta(months =+ 1, days =- 1)
edate = sdate + relativedelta(months =+ month_per)

rng_bop = pd.date_range(bop1, freq = 'MS', periods = pers)
rng_eop = pd.date_range(eop1, freq = 'M', periods = pers)

ops_line = ops >= rng_bop and ops <= rng_eop

#outputs
print(sdate)
print(edate)
print(rng_bop)
print(rng_eop)
```

If someone has a better alternative to my method, I'd be open to it - I'm trying to translate excel stuff into python and might not be doing it super effectively.

My end goal for this part is to be able to adjust the period by months, quarters or semi-annual or years, but I'd be happy with just months for now. The EOP line should be the (BOP + Period - 1 day).

I also don't think that my ops_line definition will work - I'm trying to create a boolean array from the logical operators. Any points?

Comment: I would like to advice you to comment your code or to at least  use proper naming for your variables.

Comment: Would you care to expand on what you mean by proper naming?

Comment: like what do you mean by `rng_bop`? i mean of course you understand it and know its abbreviation of some word and might even think how can people not catch it but in really a lot of us will skip answering such question because the code seems ambiguous. I you have answered questions on stack overflow before you most likely know that we, at least, i jump onto the code and read and try make sense out of it, as well as try to find holes in before i read the question, so when we/i encounter a question where variables dont make sense to me i skip it. I hope you take this as an input not criticism

Answer (score 1):

it should be `months += 1, days-= 1` not`months =+ 1, days =- 1` as the latter one assigns months and days to 1, and -1 respectively

Comment: I received invalid syntax error from doing that. Dateutil's example code seems to use =+ or =- in their examples...

Comment: are you trying to set the values to +1 and-1? or to increment and decrement by 1 respectively?  if the latter is what you are trying to do then the syntax that i have provided is the correct one. in fact that goes for all programming languages not only python

Comment: This is not the issue. The OP wants to use the values +1 and -1 as arguments to relativedelta

Answer (score 0):

As Leo Wahyd mentions `=+` / `=-` is invalid syntax in most languages.

Reading the [documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html):

> years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds:
>       Relative information, may be negative (argument is plural); adding
>       or subtracting a relativedelta with relative information performs
>       the corresponding aritmetic operation on the original datetime value
>       with the information in the relativedelta.

I think, actually, it it should be:

```
eop1 = bop1 + relativedelta(months = 1, days = -1)
edate = sdate + relativedelta(months = month_per)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with pandas date range. I tried using [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)  with no success, then I discovered [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#period):

> Adding and subtracting integers from periods shifts the period by its own frequency. Arithmetic is not allowed between Period with different freq (span).

It turns out the answer is actually really simple! Assuming your `Period` and `PeriodRange` objects have `freq == "M"` you can add to them by adding regular numbers:

```
>>> period
Period('2020-01', 'M')
>>> period + 1
Period('2020-02', 'M')
>>> period_range
PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05', '2020-06',
             '2020-07', '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

>>> period_range + 1
PeriodIndex(['2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05', '2020-06', '2020-07',
             '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

I know this question is quite old now, but hopefully my answer is helpful to somebody!